# JSON object to Google.visualization.DataTable

Tags: jquery

i am trying to convert a `json` object to `DataTable` ,

```
var obj=  ""   
  {\"Total\":28,\"Submitted\":10,\"Pending\":3,\"Confirmed\":6,\"Selected\":1,
 \"Redirected\":7,\"NotSelected\":1,\"Cancelled\":2,\"Paid\":0}""
```

i tried so many codes but nothing seems working. i am trying like `String --> Array--> DataTable`. but not able to convert this on Array itself

```
obj.replace('{','').replace('}','').split(',');
```

Second Approach

```
 var value = JSON.stringify(obj);
                var blkstr = [];
                $.each(value, function (idx2, val2) {
                    blkstr.push(val2);
                });
```

The Array will be converted like

```
 //Object
   var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
//Column Declaration        
        data.addColumn('string', 'Legend');

                data.addColumn('number', 'count');
   //Insertion
```

this can be very easy if i go by object Property `[obj.Total]`. but then this will very hard to maintain for future changes.

Comment: You must be getting a syntax error as your `obj` value has a lot of unescaped double quotes.

Comment: `DataTable` in server side or jQuery table plugin?

Comment: its not a plugin nor server side . these are `Google.visualization.DataTable`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i updated it, its actual output which i receive from server

Answer (score 0):

First point is you should be using JSON.parse to convert from json string to javascript object and JSON.stringyfy to convert other way round.

```
var value = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Then you can get the keys from the first object of the array(if its array) and then write function to create columns from the array.

```
function Object_keys(obj) {
        var keys = [], name;
        for (name in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                keys.push(name);
            }
        }
        return keys;
    }
  var keys = Object_keys(value[0]);
  for (var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
       data.addColumn('string', keys[i]);
  }
```

But you should have some other way to tell the datatype details also. Supposing you have some other array with column name and datatype it would be easier to write generic function.